# Facebook event picture resolution Graph Api bug?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get event picture by:

http://graph.facebook.com/{eventid}/picture

and it worked fine a while ago (few months ago I guess), and then I could set even resolution, and get exactly that resolution of the image.

Now it does not work, The biggest resolution I can get is 200x200 when I set type:large. And picture is always cropped to square.

What is going on? Is it Graph Api bug? How can I download normal picture in usable resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cover field ought to get you a full size picture...  http://graph.facebook.com/{eventid}?fields=cover